# CSS triangle has no point

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Here is what is happening:

[image: Stubby triangle!]

CSS:

```
.speech-box {
    height:76px;
    width:220px;
    padding:6px 10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4f4f4f,#000);
}

.speech-box:before {
    content:'';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; 
    border-right:5px solid #4f4f4f;
    position:relative;
    left:-15px;
    top:-3px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="speech-box">
  <span class="speech"></span>
</div>
```

And here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xqy4dLbc/

I'm guessing the problem is with my HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
display:block;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
```

to `.speech-box:before` :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xqy4dLbc/1/)**

The default display property of pseudo-element is `inline` ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)) and you can't set height on inline elements. Therefore the `height:0;` you set doesn't apply.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing this! The only issue is that the arrow is now taking up space and bumping my text down. http://jsfiddle.net/xqy4dLbc/4/ What would you recommend to fix/avoid this? Do I need to position it absolutely?

Comment: @Drewdavid yes, you can use `position:absolute` : http://jsfiddle.net/xqy4dLbc/5/ Notice the `position:relative;` on the parent and you don't need `display:block;` anymore.